# error: hd0 write error

Tags: command-line

Appears it

BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands

(initramfs)

---

Can you help me with it?

Comment: Not enough information. At the initramfs prompt, type `fsck -f /`... or `exit` then `fsck -f /` if the first command errors. Report back.

Comment: If you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and run the `Disks` app, what does the SMART info say about the drive?

Comment: I just do not want to appear that anymore.
can you give me the command?

Comment: My first two comments gave you the commands to do. What are the results of the FIRST fsck run?

Comment: /bin/sh : fsck: not found

Comment: No. At the initramfs prompt, type `fsck -f /` and if it doesn't work there, you'll have to type `exit` at the initramfs prompt, then do `fsck -f /`. I just don't remember if you have to exit first or not. If that doesn't work for you, I'll put together a more detailed answer for you. Report back.

Comment: [   32.975643] --- [ end trace 7f4c0ce105f413aa ] ---

Comment: I don't understand your last comment... but, no matter... I put together a partial answer for you to try...

Comment: Ok i wait your answer

Comment: Mi laptop it is

Comment: http://www.ceibal.edu.uy/storage/app/uploads/public/58a/c82/6b8/58ac826b8d432346953067.png

Comment: Let me know when you've completed my partial answer. Start comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Answer (score 0):

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Now, to check the SMART information in your hard drive...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `Disks` application
- select the correct disk in the left pane
- go to the "hamburger" icon and select `SMART Data & Tests`
- review the data, note if it indicates that your drive is good/bad
- run the tests